# a polygonal path with initial and final points

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $γ$ be a polygonal path with initial point $0$ and ﬁnal point $1$. What are all possible
values of 
$$
\int_{γ}(1+z^2)^{-1}dz
$$

I am a bit confused with this question. Am I supposed to equate the real and imaginary part in order to find a solution?

Please help

It would be highly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Hint: What happens if $\gamma$ is not a straight line segment joining $0$ and $1$ but some path which start at $0$, circle around one or both of the poles $\pm i$ on the integrand before ending at $1$....

Comment: You will also need to use the fact that the integral doesn't depend on the path from $0$ to $1$ in the case where it doesn't loop around any of the poles. So you might as well integrate on the line segment connecting 0 and 1 in that case.